# Mongoose promise function in forEach Loop is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

i'm writing a webshop in Node with Express and Mongoose. 
The Mongoose Models are "Product" and "Item". Every Item belongs to a Product. I want to count the Items of a Product (Stock) and serve this information to the view.

The Problem is, that the res.render part is executed before the forEach Loop is done. So "product.stock" is undefined

```
exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find()
        .lean()
        .then(products => {

            products.forEach(product => {
                Item.countDocuments({productId: product._id})
                    .then( count => {
                        product.stock = count
                    })
            });

            res.render('shop/product-list', {
                path: '/products',
                pageTitle: "All Products",
                products: products
            })
        })
        .catch(err => { return next(err) })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `async`/`await`:

```
exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find()
        .lean()
        .then(async (products) => {
            await Promise.all(products.map(async (product) => {
                product.stock = await Item.countDocuments({productId: product._id});
            });

            res.render('shop/product-list', {
                path: '/products',
                pageTitle: "All Products",
                products: products
            })
        })
        .catch(err => { return next(err) })
};
```

I changed `forEach` to `map` so that your list of `Product` would be converted into a list of `Promise`. Then [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) waits until all of the `Promise`s have completed, which will occur when `product.stock` has been set for each product. Only then will `res.render()` be called.